# Angular and Google Analytics

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add Google Analytics to my Angular app without having to add the scripts manually to the index file. My goal is to use a service that has functions you can call to initialize the analytics and track page views. Here's the main part of the service:

```js
export class GoogleAnalyticsService {
    private googleAnalyticsId: string;
    private renderer2: Renderer2;
    private scriptsLoaded: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private rendererFactory2: RendererFactory2,
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document,
        private _config: RuntimeConfigLoaderService,
        private _router: Router,
    ) {
        this.renderer2 = this.rendererFactory2.createRenderer(null, null);
        this.googleAnalyticsId = this._config.getConfigObjectKey('googleAnalyticsId');
    }

    init() {
        this.insertMainScript();
    }

    private insertMainScript() {
        if (this.googleAnalyticsId) {
            const script: HTMLScriptElement = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.onload = this.insertSecondHalfOfScript.bind(this);
            script.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${this.googleAnalyticsId}`;
            script.text = '';
            this.renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
        }
    }

    private insertSecondHalfOfScript() {
        const script: HTMLScriptElement = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = '';
        script.text = `
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
        `;
        this.renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
        this.scriptsLoaded = true;
    }

    trackSinglePageView(event: NavigationEnd) {
        if (this.googleAnalyticsId && this.scriptsLoaded) {
            console.log('logging pageview');
            gtag('config', this.googleAnalyticsId, { page_path: event.urlAfterRedirects });
        }
    }

    trackPageViews() {
        return this._router.events.pipe(
            filter((evt: RouterEvent) => evt instanceof NavigationEnd),
            tap((event: NavigationEnd) => {
                this.trackSinglePageView(event);
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

The main function to call from the `AppComponent` is `init`. That will inject the scripts onto the page. As I watch the application load, I see those scripts get added. I also see the `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js` script load in the Network tab of the developer tools. So the script is definitely there.

Then after calling the `init` function in the `AppComponent` I call the `trackPageViews` function and subscribe to the returned Observable. I filter out all the router events until the above scripts are loaded, and then filter out all events that are not `NavigationEnd` events. If the scripts are loaded and it's a NavigationEnd event, then the `trackSinglePageView` function and `gtag` is called with the necessary data. However, when this happens, I get the following error:

```
core.js:6189 ERROR ReferenceError: gtag is not defined
    at GoogleAnalyticsService.trackSinglePageView (google-analytics.service.ts:58)
    at TapSubscriber._tapNext (google-analytics.service.ts:69)
    at TapSubscriber._next (tap.js:40)
    at TapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
    at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at Subject.next (Subject.js:39)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (router.js:7593)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
```

If I don't use the service to load the analytics scripts and put them in the `head` of the app's index.html file and just track the page views, then I don't get any errors in the console. So it appears that although the scripts are loaded, `gtag` is still not defined unless the analytics scripts are in the `head`.

Is there any way to get around this? Am I doing something incorrect here? Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `(<any>window).gtag(...)`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thanks for the reply. Check out my answer below to see what ended up working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the text of the script created in the `insertSecondHalfOfScript` function was never run. It seems like that's where `gtag` is made available for the page. So instead of adding the code to that text attribute, I put it in an asset file and loaded it like I load the script in the `insertMainScript` function. So the initiation flow looks like this now:

```
init() {
    this.insertMainScript();
}

private insertMainScript() {
    if (this.googleAnalyticsId) {
        const script: HTMLScriptElement = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.onload = this.insertSecondHalfOfScript.bind(this);
        script.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${this.googleAnalyticsId}`;
        script.text = '';
        this.renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
    }
}

private insertSecondHalfOfScript() {
    const script: HTMLScriptElement = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '/assets/scripts/analytics/analytics-starting-script.js';
    script.text = '';
    this.renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
    script.onload = () => {
        this.scriptsLoaded = true;
    };
}
```

Loading the second script like this seems to work, as I now don't get the `ReferenceError` I was getting before.

Answer (score 1):

I know we did our gtag implementation by having a separate index file for dev vs prod.

You can configure you angular.json to use one or the other

```
  "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "index": {
            "input": "src/overrides/prod/index.prod.html",
            "output": "index.html"
          },
         "dev": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
            }
          ],
          "index": {
            "input": "src/overrides/qa/index.qa.html",
            "output": "index.html"
          },
```